# Particular holomorphic mappings of the Riemann sphere to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series, riemann-surfaces, mobius-transformation

I am struggling to understand what prof. Penrose says in his *"The Road to Reality"* book (9.3):

> There are many holomorphic mappings of the Riemann sphere to itself which send each hemisphere to itself, but which do not preserve the north or south poles (i.e. the points $z=0$ or $z=\infty$).These preserve the positive/negative frequency splitting but do not preserve the individual Fourier components $e^{-in\chi}$ or $e^{in\chi}$.

Then an exercise is proposed to show explicitely what these mappings are.

The first question I have in mind is whether that these holomorphic mappings of the sphere to itself necessarily correspond to Möbius transformations in the $\mathbb{C}$ plane.

Then, rather than the full solution, I am trying to find at least one example of a Möbius transformation that has the behaviour described; the only mapping that comes into my mind is a rotation through the "vertical" axis (hence a simple complex multiplication $az$ in terms of Möbius transformation) but this of course preserves the poles. I really cannot figure out how I can rotate or translate this sphere so that the north hemisphere still maps to the north, withouth keeping the north pole fixed. It really seems to me that prof. Penrose is meaning something else here, which I am not getting.

Last but not least, I am missing the connection between these holomorphic mappings and the fourier components of a function.

Any hint is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Google "Blaschke product"

Comment: The holomorphic maps $\Bbb{P^1\to P^1}$ are the rational functions $h=f/g$, sending each hemisphere to itself means that $h(z) = 1/\overline{h(\overline{z}^{\ -1})}$ which implies that $f/g(z)=e^{i\theta}\prod_{j=1}^J \frac{z-a_j}{1-\overline{a_j}z}$ and $|a_j|<1$. They are biholomorphic whenever $J=1$.

Comment: thanks both. @reuns could you please tell me the passages to retrieve $h(z)=1/\overline{h(\overline{z}^{-1})}$ for the rational function $h$? It makes sense to me that h, being continuous, should send points $z$ on the unit circle ($z\overline{z}=1$) to points on the unit circle ($h(z)\overline{h(z)}$=1), then replacing the first constraint in the second one I get the relationship you wrote, but I cannot get how this works for $|z|<1$.  I have the feeling that the maximum modulus principle is involved, as I have read it proves how any function with the properties of h is a Blaschke product.

Comment: If we use $g(z) = (z+i)/(iz + 1)$ to rotate the sphere 90 degrees, the two hemispheres become the upper half-plane $\mathrm{im}(z) > 0$ and the lower half-plane $\mathrm{im}(z) < 0$, with the corresponding "poles" being the points $i$ and $-i$.  Any Möbius transformation $f(z) = (az+b)/(cz+d)$ for which $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real and $ad-bc>0$ sends each of these hemispheres to itself, and it's easy to come up with examples that don't preserve the two poles, such as $f(z)=z+1$.  The conjugates $g^{-1}\circ f\circ g$ send the original hemispheres to themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h$ is analytic and non-zero at $e^{it}$ then (since $h(z)=\sum_k c_k (z-e^{it})^k$) so is $g(z)=1/\overline{h(\overline{z}^{\ -1})}$

If $h(e^{it}) = e^{i\theta}$ then $g(e^{it}) = e^{i\theta}$.

Thus $h$ is meromorphic $\Bbb{C\to C}$ and $|h(z)|=1$ on $|z|=1$ means that $g-h$ is analytic around $e^{it}$ and vanishes on $e^{ix},x-t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ ie. $g=h$.

Next since $h$ is analytic $\Bbb{P^1(C)\to P^1(C)}$ then it is a rational function $ h(z)=C\frac{\prod_j(z-a_j)}{\prod_i(z-b_j)}$, that $h$ sends each hemisphere to itself gives $|h(z)|=1$ on $|z|=1$ so that $h=g$ and hence $$h(z)=e^{i\theta}\prod_{j=1}^J \frac{z-a_j}{1-\overline{a_j}z}$$
Finally each $|a_j|<1$ since otherwise $h$ would have some zero on the $\infty$-hemisphere.

Comment: thanks for this explanation. I was able to follow it but there is an equality for which I still cannot convince myself. would you be so kind to detail some steps more on how to prove that $ C\frac{\prod_j(z-a_j)}{\prod_i(z-b_j)} = h(z)=e^{i\theta}\prod_{j=1}^J \frac{z-a_j}{1-\overline{a_j}z}$

Comment: $h(z)=C\frac{\prod_j(z-a_j)}{\prod_i(z-b_j)}$ gives $1/\overline{h(\overline{z}^{\ -1})}= ?$

Comment: Well, I managed to get the following identity (for $z\neq0$):

$$ C\frac{\prod_j(z-a_j)}{\prod_i(z-b_j)} = 1/\overline{C}\frac{\prod_i(1-\overline{b_i}{z})}{\prod_j(1-\overline{a_j}z)}$$then from here I think I should prove that 
a) $|C|$ should be $1$
b) $\prod_j(z-b_j) = \prod_i(1 - \overline{a_i}z) $. 

But I must be missing something. $\prod_i(1 - \overline{a_i}z)$ does not seem a monic polinomial to me. I can only see that the number of $a_j$ terms must be same as the number of $b_i$ terms (as two polynomials to be equal must have the same number of roots), but I'm stuck here...

Comment: I believe I finally got it. First of all the very obvious point that no $a_j$ should be equal to any of the $b_i$. This by definition of the original rational function $h$, otherwise the two terms $(z-a_j)$ and $(z-b_i)$ would cancel each other out. Then we can rewrite the last identity I've found as follows 

$$\prod_j(z-a_j)\prod_j(z-1/\overline{a_j})=A\prod_i(z-b_i)\prod_i(z-1/\overline{b_i})$$

Comment: As all the roots of the two polynomials must be equal, and no $a_j$ should be equal to any of the $b_i$, it follows that for each $a_j$ there exists a $b_i$ such that $b_i=1/\overline{a_j}$. Then $h(z)=C\frac{\prod_j(z-a_j)}{\prod_i(z-b_j)}=C_1\prod_j\frac{z-a_j}{1-1/\overline{aj}}$ where $C_1=\pm C$ depending on the number of $j$ terms. Regardless, requiring that $|h(1)|=1$ gives that $|C_1|=1$.